# Create CGPath From Floats without drawRect

Tags: ios, core-graphics

How does one create a CGPath with a number of floats inside a UIView without using the drawRect function?

Comment: You can create a CGPath anywhere you want.  Are you talking about *drawing* it?

Comment: Yes, adding an array of (x, y) values to a single path and then rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a path anywhere you want (a path object that is).  For that, timing is not important.  However, the only time you can render into a view's context is inside `drawRect:`.

If you want to render it to another view, you could draw the path inside of a CGBitmapContext (see `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` etc) and get a `UIImage`. out of it.

Comment: Do I just call drawRect directly then because I need to pass in an array of data so that the path can be drawn with that.

Comment: If you want drawRect to be called you need to call setNeedsDisplay or setNeedsDisplayInRect.  You can't pass any extra variables to drawRect so your path will have to be an iVar.

Answer (score 0):

With  the assumption that the values u are talking about are dimensions of the UIVIew

```
UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect dimensions];
CGPath cgpath=path.CGPath();
```